# Updating a method in Entity Framework

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, database-first

I'm new to Entity Framework and am using Database First.  I have inherited a project where I am making changes.  I have a table called Bid to which I've added column `Auciton_Status_Id`.  I then updated the **.edmx** file (whatever that is for) by opening it up and selecting Update Model from Database.  I had a **.tt** file (whatever that is for) in another project which I had to manually update by right clicking on it selecting Run Custom Tool.  Problem is that the **.tt** file in the same project as the .edmx file has an associated .cs file (with a class with signature `public partial class Entities : DbContext`) (whatever a `DBContext` is) and it has a method called

```
public virtual int MakeBid(Nullable<long> lotId, 
                           Nullable<decimal> bidValue, 
                           Nullable<System.DateTime> createdDate, 
                           Nullable<long> bidStatusId, 
                           Nullable<System.Guid> userId)
```

Problem is I want my new column `Auction_Status_Id` to be added to this method as well.  How do I do that when this is an autogenerated class?

Comment: `MakeBid` (whatever that is for...) is probably a stored procedure.

Comment: @GertArnold No it isn't, it's an automatically generated method (MakeXXX where XXX is the entity name).

Comment: @OP isn't the .cs file automatically updated after a build of your project?

Comment: @ken2k - no it isn't - is there something I need to do to affect that?

Comment: @GertArnold - I've got it thanks - it is a stored proc - please write that as an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MakeBid` is probably a stored procedure, so if you modify it in de database you can refresh the `.edmx` again.

(and make sure you know what it is for :D).